# Given $f$ defined at $G$ and $f^3,f^2$ holomorphic at G prove $f$ holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f$ defined at $G$ and $f^3,f^2$ holomorphic at G prove $f$ holomorphic

My try:
$f^3-f^2$=$f^2(f-1)$ because the LHS is holomorphic so does the RHS and then we get that $f-1$ is holomorphic and $f$ is holomorphic, is this right?

Comment: This helps you directly only where $f\ne0$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that if $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ is a continuous function with $f^2, f^3$ analytic, then $f$ is also analytic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298951/proving-that-if-f-mathbbc-to-mathbbc-is-a-continuous-function-with-f) – it is demonstrated in the answers that the continuity condition is not needed.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2015016.